# Creating New Page in Document Center

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, document-center

I have create a collection with Document Center type. The "Add page" function on Ribbon does not appear like in other types of collections. Please tell me if I can create that, and from where.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about SP 2013, but in SP 2010 you need to enable the SharePoint Server Publishing feature on the Document Center site, not just the site collection. This will create a Library called `Pages` and the Site Actions drop-down will then include the `New Page`command.